# how to check if an image exists or not in a flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, file-exists

I'm working an image.netwrok in a flutter. getting the image name from the database if the name exists in the database but the image is missing in the directory then it throwing error. my issue is that how can I will check that image exist or not in the directory. Thanks

Comment: i think ... you can use try catch ... not your Answer .. But an idea! :)

Comment: Please can you add your code and an example "bad url"